# Symfony loop language

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation

Hello everyone I come to you because I have a small problem I would like to do as sites display translated like this by examples :

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.deezer.com/en/artist/1191615/top_track">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://www.deezer.com/fr/artist/1191615/top_track">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.deezer.com/es/artist/1191615/top_track">
```

but I do not see how to create a loop and display all the translated routes that I have

in my controller :

```
/**
     * Home page
     * @Route({"fr": "/accueil", "en": "/home", "es": "/casa"},
     *     name="index", methods="GET",
     *     requirements={"_locale" = "fr|en|es"},
     *     defaults = {"_locale" = "fr"})
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        // Count advertisement total
        $count = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Advertisement::class)->findByCount();
        // get all regions
        $regions = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Region::class)->findAll();

        return $this->render('front/index.html.twig', [
            'count' => $count,
            'regions' => $regions
        ]);
    }
```

if you have a solution it would be nice to help me thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop (See: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html)

If `langs` is an array like:

```
$langs = [ "en", "fr", "es" ]
```

You can create a loop using:

```
{% for lang in langs %} 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ lang }}" href="https://www.deezer.com/{{ lang }}/artist/1191615/top_track">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: but what if i want to recover the link dynamically?

Comment: Just could use `{{ path('index', { '_locale' : lang }) }}` inside that loop